# which Backup Software?

Tags: linux, backup, ssh, rsync, windows-backup

I need to use a backup software that can backup windows server to a Linux server out side the network (the cloud)!

so far I came through the following:

Handy Backup Professional 6.7
Backup4all Professional 4.4
BatchSync Secure 3.0

what I need is,

- Possibility to backup to SSH(SFTP) or better RSYNC over SSH
- full,differential, incremental
- possibility to limit the backup snapshots history by size or numbers?
  like the total backup (snapshots) will not go over some ... GB
  or/and not more than 4 snapshots

here is another thing
what I think as an "ideal" backup system is to have

yearly (yearly archive),
monthly (last 12 moths),
weekly (last 2 or 3 weeks),
daily (last 7 days)

I know it is all depend on the data type and the storage that I have

so is there any one who can advice me for
for a good backup program (one of the above or any other)?
good backup strategy?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on superuser, so i'm going to recommend Mozy. Their [version 2.0](http://mozy.com/landing/win-2) puports to be pretty cool: it backs up locally and then backups up to their servers. Carbonite is their big competitor, they may have a similar offering. Both offer professional level services.

If this is for a big business and has to be handled in house, i'll just point you at [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com).

If you've already looked at these services and just have to Do-It-Yourself, then I don't know enough to help you. (but someone else surely will come along shortly.) I've only used a free version of [Acronis](http://www.acronis.com/) that came w/ my seagate drive. But i hear the full version is the bee's knees.

That said, I'm a big fan of not re-inventing the wheel and suggest giving these services a second look. They offer all the security and snap-shotting you wanted, and are pretty darn low priced.

Comment: we are thinking about Acronis too :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/). We use it to backup Windows 2003/2008 servers to a group of Linux servers using rsync over ssh with the [CwRsync](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650) package on the Windows servers

Answer (score 0):

You might consider [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) as well for your backup solutions. The price is [pretty comparable](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/007624.html) to rolling your own or using a third party service.

I'll admit that depending on how you want to snapshot your machine/servers/databases might affect the feasibility using Amazon S3. I'm not sure if you want to be able to pull a single file from a backup two weeks ago, or simply drop an image from back then onto a fresh/virtual machine and work from there.

There are a lot of tools and scripts emerging out there to integrate with Amazon S3, and one of them might exactly what you need. Similarly, you can use the [existing documentation](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/kbcategory.jspa?categoryID=55) to roll your own.